# Angular 4 cannot find name 'ViewChild'

Tags: angular, find, viewchild

I have this strange error and didn't find anything similar to it ..
I'm using ng2-canvas-whiteboard component for a drawing canvas on my website, everything's working perfectly except when i try to get reference to that canvas using :

```
@ViewChild('canvasWhiteboard') canvasWhiteboard: CanvasWhiteboardComponent;
```

as the official docs suggested, i'm getting this error :

```
Failed to compile.

e:/frontend/src/app/components/user/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts (15,2): Cannot find name 'ViewChild'.
```

Any suggestions ? Thank you

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You forgot to import `ViewChild` before using it

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core'
```